# Ionic Cordova placeholder splash screen still showing up

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, splash-screen

The placeholder Ionic Cordova splash screen is still showing up in our app even after replacing it with a custom splash screen.

Currently our app's fresh start up sequence is:

[placeholder ionic cordova splash screen] -> [custom splash screen] -> [app's initial view]

Desired behavior:

[custom splash screen] -< [app's initial view]

Here's the placeholder splash screen I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen that happening sometimes, especially in iOS (on a device or simulator), especially after updating icons and splashscreen images. Try removing/adding platforms using the ionic CLI.